# How can i reach wifi direct activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, wifi-direct, android-settings

How can i reach this activity?

I need this activity intent to show this activity from my code.

I want to reach that activity:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjWuw.png

Answer (score 0):

hello i am using this intent for wifi direct.

```
Intent wifidirect = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
startActivity(wifidirect);
```

Comment: I tried this, but this is not what i want. I need to navigate exactly to that activity, that i linked.